# How do I manually hide a table view cell when it's pushed?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //hide this cell.
    }
```

Bonus - is there a way to "fade out" the effect so it's not so jarring?

Comment: can't you use `deleteRowAtIndexPaths` ?

Comment: No, can you show me an example?

Comment: By "pushed" do you mean "tapped?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is a great tutorial on this topic](http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/02/uitableview-deleting-moving-and-viewing-rows/)

long story short, do something like this

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch editingStyle {
    case .Delete:
        // remove the deleted item from the model
        self.items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}
```